# How do I add a QueueManager to a Cluster as Partial Repository using PCF?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, pcf

I am using WebSphere MQ 8.0. 
I want add two Queue Managers, say QM1 and QM2, to a cluster programatically using Programmable Command Format (PCF) in Java.

I am able to add QM1 to the cluster as a full repository using the following code.

```
PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent("QM1");
agent.setCheckResponses(false);
PCFMessage[] responses;
PCFMessage request = new PCFMessage(MQConstants.MQCMD_CHANGE_Q_MGR);
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCA_REPOSITORY_NAME, "CLUSTER1");
responses = agent.send(request);
```

**How do I Add QM2 as a partial repository to the cluster?**

Any suggestions as to how I can improve/achieve this are welcome.

Comment: What you have shown in your question is not enough to add QM1 to the cluster. You still have to create cluster channels as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the same procedure as for MQSC commands but using PCF.

1. Define the `CLUSRCVR` channel specifying `CONNAME('dns or ip(port)')` and `CLUSTER('CLUSTER1')`.
2. Define the `CLUSSDR` to the primary full repository.

The QMgr will not resolve in the cluster until the last step.

Also, be sure to define your RCVR channel as `CLUSTER1.QM1` instead of as `TO.QM1` so that you never have a channel shared across clusters.

Comment: I had missed this bit. After creating the appropriate channels I got the Cluster going.